# Setting up react-bootstrap simple app

Tags: javascript, requirejs, reactjs, bower, react-bootstrap

I am setting up a getting-started app using react-bootstrap + requirejs + bower + php ( not nodejs). Very new to this spectrum of tools. so here is my app:

**.bowerrc**

```
{
  "directory": "javascript/components/",
  "analytics": false,
  "timeout": 120000
}
```

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "hello-react-bootstrap",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "requirejs": "*",
    "react": "~0.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "~0.20.0"
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Hello World</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

```
    <!-- Require Js -->
    <script data-main="javascript/setup.js" src="javascript/components/requirejs/require.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**javascript/setup.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "javascript/components",
    paths: {
        "app": "../app",
        'classnames':'classnames/index',
        'jquery': 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min',
        'react':'react/react',
        'react-bootstrap':'react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap'
    }
});

require.config({
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()
})

requirejs(["app/main"]);
```

**javascript/app/main.js**

```
//empty for now
```

**application structure**

```
── bower.json
├── index.html
├── javascript
│   ├── app
│   │   └── main.js
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── classnames
│   │   ├── react
│   │   ├── react-bootstrap
│   │   └── requirejs
│   └── setup.js
└── styles
```

I tried sth like this:
**app/main.js**

```
define(['react-bootstrap'], function(ReactBootstrap){
    var React = require('react');
    var Button= ReactBootstrap.Button;
    React.render(Button,document.body)
});
```

which gives me :
`Error: Invariant Violation: React.render(): Invalid component element. Instead of passing a component class, make sure to instantiate it by passing it to React.createElement.`

**Edit**
Disregard my question following is working for me :

**app/main.js**

```
define(['react-bootstrap'], function(ReactBootstrap){
    var React = require('react');  
    React.render(React.createElement(ReactBootstrap.Button,{bsStyle:'info'},'Hello World' ), document.body)
});
```

Comment: You need to either use JSX syntax or the proper element creation syntax. `React.render(<Button />, document.body)` or `React.render(React.createElement(Button, null), document.body);`

Comment: You can just delete your question if it's not relevant anymore.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, thanks but your solution seems to require jsx module `https://github.com/philix/jsx-requirejs-plugin` right ?

Comment: You'll either need to precompile your JSX files, use a plugin for `require`, or hand-code to React's API directly. I personally use Babel which has a reasonable way to integrate into many build pipelines.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, would you mind to write further steps to integerate JSX and Babel as you suggest for the above example ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JSX syntax in your main.js, you have to compile it. Otherwise, you only can use the React API to create your element, such as `React.createElement`. The [react starter guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) covers the concept.

I suggest you can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) which is already adopted in the [official react repository](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/package.json#L6) to transform your code. Install the babel as a CLI: `npm install -g babel`. Let's say you put all your js in `app/` folder, and execute `babel app --out-dir build`. It means you scan all js files under `app` folder and transforms them to `build/` folder.

Then, modify your entry point path in `javascript/setup.js`. Change `requirejs(["app/main"]);` to `requirejs(["build/main"]);`. It includes the transformed js files.

If you want to apply ES2015 (a.k.a ES6) to write better js, just add params to the babel CLI to compile the ES2015 modules to the module system you use. You use RequireJS, so the command will be: `babel src --out-dir build --modules amd`.